# Sorting large data without using modern operation system concept

Tags: sorting, operating-system

Someone asked a question during a interview:

> Suppose you have 64 GB of data and only 8 GB of memory is available and there is no concept of virtual memory, paging and segmentation or any other concept of modern operating system, so how will you sort 64 GB of data using only 8 GB of memory?

Comment: please suggest me a better subject name for the above question

Comment: Google *Mergesort*.

Comment: Hi Ken i know the merge sort is  the only option as in case of top to down approach it will work fine but when we starting merge function then how it will help, i think we need some modified merge sort or what?

Comment: No. As I said, mergesort. It has nothing to do with top down. Do more Googling.

Comment: What you're looking for is [external sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting). These almost always involve some variation of bottom up merge sort once beyond the initial pass that sorts data using 8GB of memory to create the initial sorted runs of data, that are then merged until a single sorted run is created.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37062366/designing-an-external-memory-sorting-algorithm/38507306#38507306