# How can I sort a very large log file, too large to load into main memory?

Tags: performance, data-structures

Given that i have a very large log file, large enough that it can not be loaded into my main memory, and i wanted to sort it somehow, what would be the most recommended sorting technique and algorithm?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A good IIS Log Viewer for large log files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157677/a-good-iis-log-viewer-for-large-log-files)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37062366/56778

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have GNU `sort`, use it. It knows how to deal with large files. For details, see the answers to [How to sort big files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120096/how-to-sort-big-files) on Unix SE. You will of course need sufficient free disk space.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an algorithm, you could apply [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

Essentially you split your data into smaller chunks and sort each chunk. Then you take two sorted chunks and merge them (this can be done in a streaming fashion, just take the smallest value of the two chunks and increment)m this results in a bigger chunk. Keep doing this until you have merged all chunks.

Comment: Plain merge sort will not do the job. Chunks get bigger by each iteration, so after some period of time they cannot be stored within the memory.

Comment: Correct, you would have to store them on disk. With a basic approach you need twice the disk space, but if the logs are stored in files with a maximum size X, then you should need at most 2*X additional diskspace, even for merging the last and biggest 2 chunks.

Answer (score 0):

install

> pip install bigsort

and then

> cat unsorted.txt | bigsort > sorted.txt

Answer (score -2):

This depends on OS.  If on Linux/Unix, you can use the sed command to print specific lines

```
sed -n -e 120p /var/log/syslog
```

Which would print line 120 of the syslog file.  You could also use head

```
head -n 15 /var/log/syslog
```

Which would print the first 15 lines of the syslog file.  There is also grep, tail, etc. for viewing portions of a large file.  More detail here on these and more:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/08/10-awesome-examples-for-viewing-huge-log-files-in-unix

For Windows, there is [Large Text File Viewer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/largetextfile/)

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?